# Loop thru Dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want to go through a dictionary whose values are lists.

```
books = {'(unknown)': ['Book Title xyz', 'Book Link']}
print('books=', books)
for book_variant, book_info in books.items():
    print('book_variant='), book_variant
    print('book_info[0]='), book_info[0]
    print('book_info[1]='), book_info[1]
```

The printout is:

```
books= {'(unknown)': ['Book Title xyz', 'Book Link']}
book_variant=
book_info[0]=
book_info[1]=
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: closing brakcets`()` too early for `print` statement.  Do `print('book_variant=', book_variant)`

Comment: Simple typo - move the parenthesis for `print` to the end of the line, flagging for closure due to a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('book_variant=', book_variant)
print('book_info[0]=', book_info[0])
print('book_info[1]=', book_info[1])
```

Just fix your parenthesis, the variables are out of print()